# jQuery cannot compare data AJAX returns

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a form to check if a surname already exists in the database.

It seems like it is working, it checks the database and returns values, eg the number, as a string, of times the surname exists, or 'none' if they did not enter a surname.

The problem I am having is when I try to display the results.

JavaScript:

```
sName = $('#sName'), sInfo = $("#sInfo");
sName.blur(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "sName="+$(this).attr("value"),
            url: "check.php",
            beforeSend: function(){
                sInfo.html("<font color='blue'>Checking Surname...</font>");
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "none")
                {
                    sInfo.html("<font color='red'>No Surname Entered</font>");
                }
                else if(data != "0")
                {
                    sInfo.html("<font color='red'>Surname Exists</font>");
                }
                else
                {
                    sInfo.html("<font color='green'>Surname Not Found</font>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

check.php:

```
//database connection stuff

extract($_REQUEST);

if(!empty($sName))
{
    $sql = "SELECT sName FROM student WHERE sName='$sName'";
    $rsd = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $sql) or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($DBConnect));
    $msg = mysqli_num_rows($rsd); 
    mysqli_free_result($rsd);
    mysqli_close($DBConnect);
}
else
{
    $msg = "none";
}
echo $msg;
```

No matter what the value of `data` is (eg "1", "2", "0", "none") the `sInfo` div always displays "Surname Exists".

When I change it to display

```
else if(data != "0")
                    {
                        sInfo.html("<font color='red'>Surname Exists..."+data+"</font>");
                    }
```

The result is Surname Exists...0 or Surname Exists...none when it should instead display No Surname Entered or Surname Not Found...

What am I doing wrong?

thanks.

Comment: Not the main issue here, but I'd feel bad if I wouldn't tell you that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please consider not creating your queries with string concatenation.

Comment: I do plan on using PDO to help secure the database stuff once I get it working.

Comment: I think you should compare `data.Message` with `"none"` and the others, not just `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
data: "sName="+$(this).attr("value"),
```

to

```
data: {"sName":$(this).attr("value")},
```

jquery will format it correctly in the post body

Comment: Changed it as suggested. Same error still occurs. But now `data` returns "none" no matter what is entered into the form.

Comment: alert out data in the callback just so you can get an idea if the success is firing and what the contents of data is if it does

Comment: when using `data: {"sName":$(this).attr("value")},` no matter what is entered into the form returns "none". When using `data: "sName="+$(this).attr("value"),` alert displays 0 when I mash the keyboard, 1 when I type in a known surname and none whn I leave it blank. Message displayed in `sInfo` is "Surname Exists" in all cases.

Comment: print_r $_REQUEST in php and see what you are getting on the server side

Comment: Blank: `Array ( [sName] => ) none` Keyboard Mash:`Array ( [sName] => j;osdiajf;dl ) 0` Known Name: `Array ( [sName] => tester ) 1` the none, 0 and 1 are results of the `echo $msg` not part of the `print_r`

Comment: Life should be good then. Make the sure in the php file you don't have any extra spaces coming through, like before the php open tag, another thing you can do is on the js side test against `$.trim(data)` instead of `"0"`. I'm guess you have extra whitespace in there that is makeing "0" !== "   0"

Comment: another option would be to test against `0` instead of `"0"` this will cause javascript to coerce the type to an integer effectively trimming it for you.  `"  0" != "0"` but `"  0" == 0`

Comment: WOW. well don't I feel stupid now.. doing `$.trim(data)` before the if statements fixed it. There must have been hidden white space somewhere...

Comment: good practice is to make sure row 1 col 1 of the file is `<?php` and just completely drop the ending php tag. (This is coding standards for Zend Framework)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30373/discussion-between-jake-and-orangepill)